# What's another word for aggressively turning over?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms, gestures

Looking for something to describe those scenes in a movie where a person aggressively turns over in bed, pulling the sheets over them and whatnot. I've left it at "turning over" for now, but I was wondering if there was a word to convey the frustration or anger that comes with certain scenes. Sort of like this, except angrier:

[image]

Comment: And you want a **single word** for that?!

Comment: This is *tossing and turning* in bed.

Comment: *Rolling* is more aggressive than *turning*

Comment: I don't think there is a SW for that... the Q is based on a single giffy, and it looks a little like" yeah, yeah go away". That makes it POB.